# Can't properly print non-English characters like ë in Windows console

Tags: java, unicode

For some weird reason I can't seem to print ë in Java.

```
public class Eindopdracht0002test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("\u00EB");
  }
}
```

It's supposed to print `"België"` (dutch for Belgium) however it returns `"Belgi├½"`.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Perhaps you console (`cmd.exe`?) isn't configured properly for the encoding that `StdOut` uses.

Comment: Evidently it prints UTF-8 (multibyte sequences) which is read as single byte encoding (probably Windows platform encoding, maybe Cp1252).

Comment: Where you are printing it to? Console? Web page? Other?

Comment: @KirillBulygin It doesn't work either with system.out.print

Comment: @JoopEggen I'm just starting programming and never had to use unicode or other such things before. How would I fix this?

Comment: @Pshemo I'm printing it to the windows command prompt

Comment: StdOut must have been opened with UTF-8, so change that to Cp1252. Look whether you somewhere redefined the java system property `file.encoding` like -Dfile.encoding UTF-8.  Or do simply `System.out.println`.

Comment: Without seeing the implementation of `StdOut`, where the problem likely exists, do you want us to *guess* what it's doing wrong?

Comment: @JoopEggen I have tried using system.out.println already. It doesn't work either

Comment: @Andreas I've edited my question to include the whole program and no external libraries. Does this help?

Comment: Please include what operating system, shell, and encoding you're using; this will only work in the encoding you specify.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I'm using Windows 10, java build 1.8.8_151-b12. I'm using Dr. Java (Yes I know it's bad but school forces us to use it.) I haven't speciefied any kind of encoding nor can I find it in any of the preferences/settings in Dr. Java

Comment: What is your console codepage? You can check it with `chcp` command.

Comment: @Pshemo Active codepage: 850

Comment: Try creating writer like `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "cp850"), true);` and then call `out.println("\u00EB");`.

Comment: Refresh this page to see corrected code example, or simply change `cp852` to `cp850`.

Comment: @Pshemo it returns "OutputStreamWriter cannot be resolved to a type" Am I missing something (I do have "import java.io.PrintWriter;" at the top of my program.

Comment: You also need to `import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;`.

Comment: @Pshemo I added it but now I get "Unhandeled exception type java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException"

Comment: OK, instead of handling that exception lets simplify our code by letting exception being rethrown from method. Modify your `main` method (I am assuming you placed that code there) to `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {`

Comment: @Pshemo YES! Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UTF-8 `ë` is written as `11000011 10101011` (source: https://unicode-table.com/en/00EB).
Console in Windows is using code pages which are 8-bit mappings to characters (you can check code page of your console with `chcp` command). This means when `ë` is sent to output stream (console) as `11000011 10101011` bits, console sees it as two characters, which in [850 code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) (based on your comments) are mapped to:

- `├` - 11000011 (195 in decimal)
- `½` - 10101011 (171 in decimal)

If you don't want to use UTF-8 encoding you can create separate Writer and specify different encoding which will translate characters to bytes according to that encoding. To do so you can use

[`OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-)

which in your case may look like

```
OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "cp850") osw = OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "cp850");
//  needed encoding ------------^^^^^
```

since you want send characters with specified encoding to standard output stream.

To use `println` method and ensure it will automatically flush its data you can wrap created `OutputStreamWriter` in

[`PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.OutputStream-boolean-)

like

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(osw, true);
```

You can also do both these things in one line:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "cp850"), true);
```

Now if you use `out.println("\u00EB");` it should use recognize `ë` character and use `cp850` encoding to locate its mapping (which is `137`) and send proper byte representation (here `10001001`) to `System.out` (console).